# Apache Server add client IP in a custom header before forwarding request

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, reverse-proxy

Scenario is such that the Apache Http Server will act as a reverse proxy and sit in front of the main application server. In the application server the client IP address needs to be logged.

My requirement is to capture the client IP address and then add this IP address as a custom request header (e.g. TRUEIP=123.123.123.123) and forward it to the application server.
Please note I have read articles about logging the original client IP to the apache logs. But my requirement to access the IP address and add it to a header. 
Also I did try to access the environment variables using "%{h}i" or "%{h}e" but in this case the header value was displayed as "i=18" (without the quotes). In fact the header value was printed the same "i=18" for User-Agent, Referer also.

Please help my out with a solution.

I use Apache 2.4.28 (from apache lounge) on windows 7. The application server used in Oracle OC4J (but I need to do configurations at Apache end only as application can be different in different environments).

Comment: See the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) as  `X-Forwarded-For` is already included in the headers.  No need for non-standard headers.

Answer (score 8):

Something along the lines of:

```
RequestHeader set TRUEIP "%{REMOTE_ADDR}s"
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```